# Trying to Select the sum of cells that are round number amounts

Tags: sql

I am trying to SUM a column only IF the cell is a round number. Doesn't matter what the number is.

I am unsure of what wildcard to put and if I need to put it into parenthesis or not.

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN(TXN_AMOUNT_BASE = '%0.00' 
        THEN TXN_AMOUNT_BASE ELSE 0 END))AS 
       Round_Dollar_Wires
  FROM IDP_PRD_INTERFACE.AML_L3_HPT_GRP.V_TRANSACTIONS
  GROUP BY ACCOUNT_SOURCE_REF_ID
 LIMIT 100;
```

I am looking to get the sum of every transaction that is a round dollar amount. (So sum every transaction that looks like $1000.00, $100.00, $50.00, $ $1500.00. But not $1555.00, $50.45, or $125.)

Comment: `TXN_AMOUNT_BASE` is not of a string data type, is it?

Comment: No, it is not a string data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue as follows:

```
 select 
 CUSTOMER_SOURCE_UNIQUE_ID
 ,ACCOUNT_SOURCE_REF_ID
 ,CASE WHEN TXN_AMOUNT_BASE LIKE '%00.00' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END as Round_Dollar
from IDP_PRD_INTERFACE.AML_L3_HPT_GRP.V_TRANSACTIONS
```

Answer (score 1):

The modulo function will depend on your RDMBS, but I think you basically want to divide by 10, based your examples.

So `case when TXN_AMOUNT_BASE % 10 = 0...`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do something like this:

```
sum(case when cast(txn_amount_base / 10 as int) * 1000 = txn_amount_base * 1000
         then txn_amount_base
    end)
```